# ldlinux.sys file on usb stick

Tags: 16.04, usb-drive

I've got file named `ldlinux.sys` which is on USB stick, next to a folder named `System Volume Information`.

I'm pretty sure that folder was created by Windows, but I know nothing about the file `ldlinux.sys`, and I wonder if I can remove them (the folder and the file) without corrupted the USB stick.

```
$ ls -l
total 36
-r--r--r-- 1 user user 32768 june  10 19:33 ldlinux.sys
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user  4096 may   16 21:14 System Volume Information

$ ls -l System\ Volume\ Information/
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 76 may   16 21:14 IndexerVolumeGuid
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 12 june   6 01:16 WPSettings.dat
```

Comment: It looks like it is a boot file possibly put on there by the Rufus application (see https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/487)  that is used to create bootable USB drives.  If you are not booting to it, it is safe to get rid of it.  I would say you could format this drive is that is what you want.

Comment: I never use Rufus lol, I use UnetBootIn or `dd` with Ubuntu (and I find a way to corrupt the inod table of an USB stick by not being patient, that's not this one)

Comment: Unetbootin could put it on there too I suppose.  Pendrive Linux sets up something very similar as well, which I have used many times.  It is a boot file though used by one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ldlinux.sys` is a component of [sysliunx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYSLINUX), a boot loader for linux. If you are not intending on booting from the usb stick, you can delete it.

Comment: So this file would be recreated when I would transform this USB stick into bootable USB?

Comment: @damadam Correct.